# Populating a sub-group in firebase Database

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database

I have an activity where i want to send a custom message to a sub-group in my database when a button is clicked. I tried to check for a user_id and send the message to those user id's, My problem is that when i click the button(status) it only sends that message to one person.

This is my Activity:

```
public class messageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button status;
private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
private String mCurrentUserId;
private String userName;
private String user_id;
private String message;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUserRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    gettingIntent();



    status = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rescue);
    status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

                addUpdateMessage();
                addTeamUpdateChat();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Team Update message was successfully sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });



    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Status");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);

    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


        mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        mUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }



private void checkUser() {

    if (mCurrentUserId == null) {
        sendToStart();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void gettingIntent() {

    Intent intent =getIntent();
    user_id = intent.getStringExtra("user_id");
}

private void addTeamUpdateChat() {



            String current_user_ref="Team_Updates/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+user_id;
            String reciever_user_ref= "Team_Updates/"+user_id+"/"+mCurrentUserId;

            DatabaseReference team_push_key = mRootRef.child("Emergency_Messages").child(mCurrentUserId).child(user_id).push();

            String push_key = team_push_key.getKey();

            Map messageMap = new HashMap();
            messageMap.put("userName", userName + " Is now a new Member of the team.");        
            messageMap.put("type","text");
            messageMap.put("from",mCurrentUserId);
            messageMap.put("seen",false);
            messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
            messageUserMap.put(current_user_ref+ "/"+push_key,messageMap);
            messageUserMap.put(reciever_user_ref+ "/"+push_key,messageMap);

            mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    if(databaseError!=null){
                        Log.d("TAG",databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                }
            });

    }



private void addUpdateMessage() {

    mRootRef.child("Team_Updates_Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("seen",false);
                chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("Team_Updates_Chat/"+mCurrentUserId+"/"+user_id, chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("Team_Updates_Chat/"+user_id+"/"+mCurrentUserId, chatAddMap);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if(databaseError!= null){
                            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Error: "+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(currentUser == null){

        sendToStart();

    } else{
        mCurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    }

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();



}

private void sendToStart() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(messageActivity.this, Home.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();

}
```

}

I'm Still learning Programming in Android Studio, Is there Any suggestions on how i should approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a message only to single user because you are getting only a single user. To send a message to multiple users, you need to loop to get all those users and then send the message to all of them.